# Discrete valuation fields and representation as power series

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $(K,v)$ be a discrete valuation field ($v$ is surjective). Let $\mathcal O$ be the ring of integers of $v$ and moreover let $\mathfrak p$ be the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal O$. Then we have the following theorem:

> Let $R\subset\mathcal O$ be a set of representatives for the residue field $\mathcal O/\mathfrak p$ such that $0\in R$. Then the completion $\widehat K$ (of $K$ w.r.t. $v$) **is the set**:
>   $$\mathscr L:=\left\{\sum_{i\ge -m} a_i\pi^i\,:\, a_i\in R,\;a_{-m}\neq 0,\ \right\}$$
>   where $\pi\in\mathcal O$ is an element such that $v(\pi)=1$. In other words every element of $\widehat K$ has a unique representation as convergent power series.

**Fundamental remark**: We can endow $\mathscr L$ with a field structure by transferring the field structure of $\widehat K$. *Note that here the product in $\mathscr L$ is not the usual convolution of power series* since $\widehat K$ is a ring of Cauchy sequences (modulo...). Here I must link [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616275/convolution-vs-term-wise-product) other question of mine.

---

Now consider the following example:

$k$ is a field and consider the ideal $\mathfrak p=(t)\subset k[t]$. Then $k(t)$ is a discrete valuation field w.r.t the $\mathfrak p$-adic valuation $v_{\mathfrak p}$; moreover $\mathcal O=k[t]$ and the residue field $\mathcal O/\mathfrak p$ is isomorphic to $k\subseteq k(t)$.
It follows that $k$ is itself a system of representatives and
$$\mathscr L=k((t))=\left\{\sum_{i\ge{-m}} a_it^i\,:\, a_i\in k\right\}$$

If we want to consider $k((t))$ as a field **through the above theorem**, we notice that this  field structure isn't the same as the "usual" field structure on $k((t))$. Here, with the term usual I mean the component wise addition and the convolution product of power series.

In other words I don't agree with the following proposition:

> "$k((t))$ is the completion of $k(t)$ w.r.t. $v_{\mathfrak p}$"

Why is it instead true?

---

**Edit:** The question has been edited because it contained many imprecisions.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Are you observing that the definitions seem very different, but the results are the same? Or are you fearful that the results are in fact different?

Comment: I was trying to check that $k((t))$ is the completion of $k(t)$, but it seems that I concluded that this is not the case.

Comment: Then I have to ask: have you found a pair $f$ and $g$ such that the sum or product is different in the two rings? Or a sequence that’s convergent in one but not the other? The admitted fact that the two definitions look very different is not sufficient for concluding that the two are different. I find your question reasonable, even though I disagree with you, because I know of a parallel situation where two things look alike but are different, it’s the case of power series over $\Bbb Q_p$ and look at the $p$-adic topology induced from $\Bbb Z[[x]]$, and the coefficientwise topology.

Comment: For example lets multiply componentwise $a_0+ a_1t+...$ and $b_0+ b_1t+...$. You get the sequence of partial sums $a_0b_0$, $a_0b_0+a_0b_1t+ a_1b_0t+ a_1b_1t^2$, ....  Here the second term is different from the second term of the sequence of partial sums obtained by convolution which is $a_0b_0+a_1b_0t+ a_0b_1t$.  (Even if the limit is the same).

Comment: @Dubious if the limit is the same, then they differ by a null sequence, so they will be equal in the completion.

Comment: Yes, the comment of @Mathmo123 may well be pointing out the source of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, now I got it.